# Gradle with Mockito and MockMaker plugin

Tags: android, mockito

Trying to handle a problem with mocking Kotlin final classes. I used org.mockito:mockito-inline libs that uses org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker.
All works fine when start tests from Android Studio, but when I use "gradlew test" command I get error 
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker" the reason

[image]

Can anyone suggest hot to run test via gradle just like if the test is run from Android Studio?